# Answers for questions are not ordered by votes

Tags: support, answers, sorting

I have noticed that now the answers to questions are not sorted by votes anymore. Is this a new feature?

For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6834037/initialize-a-long-in-java/6834049#6834049) (though you may need to refresh... random, you know..)

I assume it is related to some meta question, but I didn't find such.

Comment: Could you point to an example? I don't see it....

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can sort by **3 (three)** things:

[image: question sort]

If the sort is **not** set to `votes` then it will either sort by `oldest` or by most recently `active`

Comment: I have totally missed that. Thank you!

Comment: @BinyaminSharet No problem ^_^

Comment: +1 for stylish red circles!

Answer (score 7):

You have a tab with three entries, `active`, `oldest` and `votes`. I guess you have accidently selected a different tab, reselect `votes` and everything is fine.

Comment: Not enough freehand circles :-P

Comment: Ahahaha right just seen you were 48 seconds faster, but with gfx. Congratulations ^^

Comment: Haha. make that 48 seconds faster :-P

Comment: Oy... you edited your comment ^_^